# Why didn't HLOOKUP with an approximate match (true) return accordingly the next largest value that is less than lookup_value

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, lookup

Please help me explain the result from `HLOOKUP()` function with the logical value `= TRUE` as the data below

`B6`: returns `0.35` when choosing a smaller lookup_array

[B6: returns 0.35 when choosing a smaller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Un2sx.png)

At `B5`: I understand the result: firstly, Excel sorted the first row in ascending order, left to right (then we have b c d f g m); secondly, chose the next largest value that is less than lookup_value `g`; hence `f` was picked and the result was `0.6` accordingly.

The explanation is correct in `B7`, but not correct in `B6`. At `B6`, the **table_array** is narrower, but everything is the same.

**My questions are:**

1. What is the logic of return at `B6`? I even changed `B1` to `d`, the result at `B6` was `0.3` accordingly.
2. Does `HLOOKUP()` see from the last column of the array (right to left), and no sort? If yes, when does this rule work because it is contradicted `B5` above?

Please see the picture below. `B18` returns `0.32`. Look like the rule is first picked from the right to left, and smaller than the lookup_value `z`

But why `B19` and `B20` return `#N/A`?

[image: B19 and B20 return #N/A. B18 returns 0.32 instead of 0.25 as the rule at B5]

If I change the first cell in the first array to `b` (see cell `H14` in the below picture). `B19` and `B20` (`I19` and `I20` in the below picture) now return `0.25`

[image: B19 and B20 don't return #N/A if the first cell of the lookup_value is 'b' instead of 'u']

---

Additional information: I found that `HLOOKUP()` will find the last value (from right to left) in the array that has the same format as the **lookup_value**. I attached an image to show it as cell `C31` and `I31`.

But the unexplained result is `I33` as mentioned in question `2`

[image: find in the same format part to the lookup_value]

I changed values in the lookup_array to see the result in every change, and tried to see the logic and what repeated this time and the last time. I even asked ChatGPT 4.0 but it didn't work, answers are nonsense.

---

update 2:
I used the function in question 1 (first image) in a new spreadsheet in Excel, in spreadsheet in Google Drive and OneDrive as well.
B5 was the same return.
B6 returned the same.
But B7 is 0.3 in Onedrive and 0.35 in Google Drive.

[Onedive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Un2sx.png)
[GoogleDrive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8D27.png)

Comment: Long story short: "If range_lookup is TRUE, the values in the first row of table_array must be placed in ascending order: ...-2, -1, 0, 1, 2,... , A-Z, FALSE, TRUE; otherwise, HLOOKUP may not give the correct value. If range_lookup is FALSE, table_array does not need to be sorted."

Comment: @user11222393 thank you. That's what I mean in the first paragraph. But It is contracdicted to others, I can't explain results at some cells by this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the explaination here, it makes sense to me: https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/2637/Six-Reasons-Why-Your-VLOOKUP-or-HLOOKUP-Formula-Does-Not-Work.html

The HLOOKUP(), VLOOKUP() may return an error or incorrect value.
To solve it, if we omit or use TRUE for range_lookup, we must sort the first column/row

Answer (score 1):

According to your first paragraph it seems your understanding of the (H)LOOKUP function is incorrect. There is no mechanism where Excel auto-sorts given parameters. Furthermore with approximate matching the function is not actually taking into consideration exact matches but the 1st value larger then given input. Sidenote: your given result in `B7` is incorrect, or you have got the wrong lookup-value in `A7` (which would probably need to be 'c').

So IMHO, the answer lays in the [MS-documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/hlookup-function-a3034eec-b719-4ba3-bb65-e1ad662ed95f) which is quite clear on the matter. With using approximate matching you need to input a ***sorted array (ascending)***. Otherwise you may end up with unexpected results.

If you fail to input a sorted array, the underlaying process of (H)LOOKUP will stop at the 1st element found larger than the lookup-value before *returning the value before that one* except in the the case when the lookup value is smaller then the 1st element in the array. In your case of `B5`, you are looking for 'g'. The 1st value found larger than 'g' is 'm'. And since your input is ***not*** sorted the value it will return is the value that belongs to 'f' (since that is the value situated right before the "matched" value).

So, I'd advise to carefully read the documentation and take note of said behaviour as described above. For now you could try:

[image]

Formula in `B5`:

```
=HLOOKUP(A5:A7,SORT(A1:F2,1,,1),2,1)
```

An alternative, as given by [@MayukhBhattacharya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8162520/mayukh-bhattacharya) would be `XLOOKUP()`:

```
=XLOOKUP(A5:A7,A1:F1,A2:F2,,-1)
```

Comment: Thank you. Apologise for incorrect function in the first image I updated. I made a mistake formatting

1st paragrapah: I don’t think I understand incorrectly. I was based on the explanation on the Microsoft site.
I used it in a new spreadsheet in Excel, Google Drive and OneDrive. B5 was same. B6 was same. But B7 is 0.3 in Onedrive & 0.35 in Google Drive. Please see updated screenshots above – at the bottom

I am using this in a formula to find the last cell in each row that have no blank. The formula works for the range. My aim is just learn more about the HLOOKUP() function